# Scroll up button for website not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to put a "scroll up" button on my website, and for some reason it isn't working correctly. The button does appear on the page, but for whatever reason whenever I attempt to click it it just redirects me to the front page of the site. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

```
<script> 
$(function(){$.fn.scrollToTop=function(){$(this).hide().removeAttr("href");if($(window).scrollTop()>="100"){$(this).fadeIn("slow")}var scrollDiv=$(this);$(window).scroll(function(){if($(window).scrollTop()<="1000"){$(scrollDiv).fadeOut("slow")}else{$(scrollDiv).fadeIn("slow")}});$(this).click(function(){$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:0},"slow")})}}); 
$(function(){$("#toTo_button").scrollToTop();}); 
</script> 
<style> 
#toTo_button { width:70px;text-align:center;padding:5px;position:fixed;bottom:10px;right:12px;cursor:pointer;color:#666;text-decoration:none; } 
#ups a img { opacity:0.7; -moz-opacity:0.7; filter:alpha(opacity=70); } 
#ups a:hover img { opacity:1.0; -moz-opacity:1.0; filter:alpha(opacity=100); } 
</style> 
<div id="ups"> 
<a href="/" id="toTo_button"><img src="http://full4dl.ucoz.com/Support/ups.png" alt="" /></a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Are You calling the function based on the click event ?

Comment: You really should format and indent your code better.  Also, use http://jsfiddle.net to prepare an example that people can easily run and edit.

Comment: Did any of our code help? If so, could you mark one as the solution, or let us know what happened when you tried to run it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent the default action when you click the anchor, as `<a href="/" ...` will surely redirect to the home page:

```
$(function () {
    $.fn.scrollToTop = function () {
        $(this).hide().removeAttr("href");
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= "100") {
            $(this).fadeIn("slow")
        }
        var scrollDiv = $(this);
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() <= "1000") {
                $(scrollDiv).fadeOut("slow")
            } else {
                $(scrollDiv).fadeIn("slow")
            }
        });
        $(this).click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();         // ding ding ding
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, "slow")
        })
    }
});
$(function () {
    $("#toTo_button").scrollToTop();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues with your code.

First, you have to trigger the function by binding it to a click event.

```
$('#toTo_button').click(function(event) {
    //do your scroll magic here
});
```

Secondly, when you trigger that click event, you should pass the event and call `event.preventDefault()`. This prevents the browser from automatically calling a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.preventDefault()` on the click event of the anchor tag, this will stop the default redirect to the homepage of the site(as you have written `a href="/"`).

This should resolve the issue.